Is it possible to handle isLoading of different endpoints centrally?
In RTK Query, I have two mutations that fire up different endpoints;
const [fetchById] = useFetchByIdMutation();
const [sendId] = useSendIdMutation();

On my component,I use these two different methods on two different button clicks and I need to pass isLoading state to a component I have which renders a loader;
<Loader blocked={isLoading}fullScreen />
I access the loader states as this;
const [fetchById, {isLoading: isFetchByIdLoading}] = useFetchByIdMutation();
const [sendId, {isLoading: isSendByIdLoading}] = useSendIdMutation();

<Loader blocked={isSendByIdLoading || isFetchByIdLoading} fullScreen />
This actually makes Loader appear onthe screen,but am I actually suppose to handle loading states for each and every mutation I use inside a component? Is there any functionality that centralizes this? Or am I completely misusing this?
I am thinking about setting the state of isLoading for each button click to reduxstore then use that state for the Loader component.

"but am I actually suppose to handle loading states for each and every mutation I use inside a component?" - Basically, yes, since inside each component is where the mutation is triggered, it makes sense to also use the mutation's returned metadata so the component can track the statuses.

I think you got it, and you can't do really better with these hooks.
You could combine them in your own custom hook:
function useIdQueries() {
  const [fetchById, {isLoading: isFetchByIdLoading}] = useFetchByIdMutation();
  const [sendId, {isLoading: isSendByIdLoading}] = useSendIdMutation();
  return [sendId, fetchById, {isLoading: isSendByIdLoading || isFetchByIdLoading}];
}

But the gain is really minor, excepting if you want to combine lots of queries.
About your last idea:

I am thinking about setting the state of isLoading for each button click to reduxstore then use that state for the Loader component.

Managing a loading flag in a Redux store is a little bit over-engineering: as you don't want to share this state across components, it should remains in the component state which displays the <Loader />
